# How do I use Google AdWords to lead potential readers to my WattPad story?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, marketing, ebook, electronic-publishing

I have a 90k word story that I want to publish on WattPad, and I plan to "religiously" follow all their promotion guides.

I don't see using Google AdWords anywhere in the guide.  How can I use Google AdWords to lead potential readers to a WattPad story?